# How to delete an old Route from a Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

there.
I have a marker on a map (Google Maps APIV3) where every time I change its position I calc a new route to the closest point on the map.
And that is working fine, but also every time I change the position of the Marker the map is still keeping the old route.
I tried everything and nothing worked. How do I delete and old Route from a Map?

You can see the problem on this link http://mercurio.cafw.ufsm.br/~grupo1/ 
If you move the blue marker, it works just fine.
But if you move it again the old route is still there.

Here is the code!

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-27.357246,-53.396022),
    zoom: 14,
    maxZoom: 17,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}; 

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);
var marcador = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.355379,-53.397773);
var seuMarcador = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: marcador,
    map: map,
    icon: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png",
    title:"Mova essa marcador para seu endereço.",
    draggable: true
});

 google.maps.event.addListener(seuMarcador, 'mouseup', function(event) {
var addr = new Array(5);
    addr[0] = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.352646,-53.384881);
    addr[1] = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.344648,-53.395009);
    addr[2] = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.365562,-53.388859);
    addr[3] = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.366241,-53.401655);
    addr[4] = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.360467,-53.397476);

    //var a = new google.maps.LatLng(-27.357837,-53.395661);
    var a = event.latLng;
    var menorDistancia;
    var destinoFinal;
    var directionsDisplay;
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);


    function calcRoute(inicio,fim) {
        var start = inicio;
        var end = fim;
        var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        //I BELIVE THAT THE PROBLEM IS HERE
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Please: 1. remove the irrelevant code (the distanceMatrix has nothing to do with this question).  2. Add all the relevant code (there is no map defined in your snippet but it is used).  3. a jsfiddle or a link to a live version that exhibits the problem would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create a new DirectionsRenderer for each call, reuse the same one.  Remove this from your event listener:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```